# Can't Adjust Screen Brightness on Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6H AMDGPU Ryzen 5800H Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, lenovo, brightness, backlight, amdgpu

Got this device (Lenovo Legion 5 Gen 6) a few days ago, setting up Ubuntu (dual boot alongside Windows) on it has been a real hassle. Wifi didn't work out of the box, found out that Mediatek MT7921e Wifi card on it only works on Kernel 5.12 and above. So I'm running Ubuntu 21.10 which comes with `5.13.0-21-generic`.

Right now, I can't adjust the brightness levels on the device. It's set to Hybrid mode with Ryzen 7 5800H CPU and Nvidia RTX3060 GPU (through Windows Lenovo Vantage/BIOS).

I have tried multiple solutions including setting the kernel parameter  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.backlight=0"`. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616371/backlight-control-not-working-on-lenovo-ideapad-gaming-3-with-renoir-amdgpu).

Also tried
`acpi_backlight=vendor`
`acpi_backlight=video`
`acpi_backlight=native`, etc, but to no avail.

`inxi -Fxxz` output:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.13.0-21-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Desktop: MATE 1.26.0 wm: marco dm: LightDM 
           Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82JU v: Legion 5 15ACH6H serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 
           v: Legion 5 15ACH6H serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0T76485 WIN serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO v: GKCN44WW date: 08/30/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 49.4 Wh (59.0%) condition: 83.7/80.0 Wh (104.6%) volts: 15.9 min: 15.4 model: Celxpert L20C4PC1 
           serial: <filter> status: Unknown 
CPU:       Info: 8-Core model: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 0 cache: 
           L2: 4 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 102207 
           Speed: 2455 MHz min/max: 1200/3200 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2455 2: 3276 3: 2378 4: 1916 5: 2060 
           6: 2494 7: 2658 8: 2698 9: 2118 10: 1916 11: 1916 12: 1916 13: 1916 14: 1909 15: 1916 16: 1916 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] vendor: Lenovo driver: nvidia v: 460.106.00 
           bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:2560 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Cezanne vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus-ID: 06:00.0 
           chip-ID: 1002:1638 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 compositor: marco driver: loaded: amdgpu,ati,nvidia 
           unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~165Hz s-dpi: 98 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.41.0 5.13.0-21-generic LLVM 12.0.1) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.2 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:228e 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A 
           bus-ID: 06:00.5 chip-ID: 1022:15e2 
           Device-3: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus-ID: 06:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3 
           Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.0-21-generic running: yes 
           Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
           Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 2000 
           bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: MEDIATEK vendor: Lenovo driver: mt7921e v: kernel port: 2000 bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 14c3:7961 
           IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Bluetooth: Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-4:3 chip-ID: 0489:e0cd 
           Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: down bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes 
           address: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.86 TiB used: 29.8 GiB (1.6%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: HFS001TDE9X084N size: 953.87 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 
           serial: <filter> temp: 42.9 C 
           ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: HFS001TDE9X084N size: 953.87 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 
           serial: <filter> temp: 37.9 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 623.23 GiB used: 29.77 GiB (4.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme1n1p4 
           ID-2: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 35.6 MiB (13.9%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile 
Sensors:   Message: No sensor data found. Is lm-sensors configured? 
Info:      Processes: 382 Uptime: 57m Memory: 13.51 GiB used: 2.97 GiB (22.0%) Init: systemd v: 248 runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 11.2.0 alt: 10/11 Packages: 2139 apt: 2128 snap: 11 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.8 running-in: mate-terminal
```

Also, noticed that `driver` section in `Display` is empty if that could be an issue. I have `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` installed.

I'm avoiding using discrete graphics or any software that just adjusts the gamma values.

Answer (score 0):

([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/LenovoLegion/comments/qvabtl/amd_brightness_on_legion_5_15ach6h_82ju_hybrid/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))
Here is what I did.

1. You can use `mainline` to install the kernel version 5.16.1 RC1 and it will just work out of the box.
2. Reboot, choose recovery mode, enable networking and go to root terminal.
3. Clean install nvidia drivers: `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` then `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`